# Error 500 on Jquery Min.Map File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
GET http://domain.com/assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.map 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Any idea what's wrong with this Error? I cant seem to see any error on the log files in /var/log/error

I have these file loaded

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: Remove this line in your jqeury.js file would remove the Error @ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map Question is if i have jquery-1.10.2.min.map, how can i use it?

Comment: Look in Apache's error log.

Answer (score 1):

You can download map from jquery website http://jquery.com/download/ (here is a link to 1.10.2 map http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.map). Place it in the same directory where you keep minified version of jQuery.

Here you can read more about source maps http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Comment: thank you, i placed it in the same directory as jquery.js my minified version is this 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>